# basic function inside a function

Tags: javascript, function

```
function name(){
  var fullName = "lawrence Turton";
    
  function concat(name){
    return "Hello Mr. " + name; 
  };

  return concat(fullName);
}
```

I am currently learning javascript. the sample code is from a youtube tutorial I am watching, the lesson is about embedding function inside a function, the 1st function is named "name"  then the embedded function concat's parameter is also "name" then the return value is return concat(fullName);<--- this part really confuses me, because he used "name" thrice one when he gave a name for the the 1st function and the 2nd one as a parameter for the concat function and 3rd in the concatenated string, and since var fullName = "lawrence Turton" is define in fullName variable name, and i can't find a clear connection between "lawrence Turton"(string) and "name"(parameter)(variable),

my question here, is why can't the parameter in the function concat be (fullName) since "lawrence Turton" has already been defined in the variable FullName.

why not write it this way

```
function name(){
  var fullName = "lawrence Turton";

  function concat(fullName){
    return "Hello Mr. " + fullName; 
  };

  return concat(fullName);
}
```

I also tried this and it worked

Comment: Your concat function has a parameter called name and only `name` can be used inside the `concat` function. Using `fullName` is also possible. You should learn in your course about scopes, it will be explained then.

Comment: "*why can not write it this way*" -> "*I also tried this and it worked*" evidently you found you can. The question doesn't make sense.

Comment: *why can't the parameter in the function concat be (fullName)* It can be

Comment: Function parameter names can be anything you want them to be. But it's a good idea not to reuse variable names, because it can be confusing which one is being referenced.

Comment: Function parameters are listed inside the parentheses () in the function definition.
Function arguments are the values received by the function when it is invoked.
Inside the function, the arguments (the parameters) behave as local variables.

Comment: thank you very much, i understand it now, function name  does't have any relationship with concat(name) the parameter receives the concat(fullName)  argument, so it can pass the value  to the return concatenated statement,

Answer (score 0):

> why can not write it this way

As you probably already found out, you can. But it's recommended that you avoid it.

Why? You may ask. Well, you should be aware that inside your function `concat`, the identifier "`fullName`" refers to the function argument and not to the variable `fullName` declared on the outter scope, this can be referred as "variable shadowing" and it's not considered a good practice (therefore we try to avoid it).

If you're willing to learn JS you will certainly come across a certain "Scope" topic, as it is one of the language's pillars. You can take a short read on it at [W3Schools: JavaScript Scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp), but I highly recommend that you dive deep into it while you're still starting to learn JS.

You can take a much, much deeper read on it [here (You Don't Know JS Yet: Scope & Closures, by Kyle Simpson)](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/scope-closures/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

The code example isn't that good because the function doesn't do what it says it does.

It's called name, but it returns a greeting to the name.

Also, you can recall `.concat()` to add more things to the end of the message.

```js
function name() {
  var fullName = "lawrence Turton";

  function concat(name) {
    return "Hello Mr. " + name;
  }
  return concat(fullName);
}

console.log(name());

console.log(name().concat("more stuff at the end."));
```

It would make more sense to use the functions as methods, so they can do more things.

In the example below, we can call `.greet()` to get a greeting, or change the username with `.setName()`.

If you look at the returned functions, we use an arrow function and an anonymous function. This is because in setName, we want to return `this` context, so we can chain the methods. This allows us to do `user.setName(name).greet()`. With an arrow function, `this` works differently, and wouldn't work the same.

Here's a link to more details: [This difference](https://dmitripavlutin.com/differences-between-arrow-and-regular-functions/#1-this-value)

```js
const createUser = (username) => ({
  greet: (greeting) => {
    if(greeting) return greeting + username;
    return `Hi, ${username}`
  },
  setName: function(_username){
    username = _username;
    return this;
  },
})

const user = createUser("John Smith");
console.log(user.greet())
user.setName("Fred")
console.log(user.greet())
console.log(user.setName("Steve").greet())
```

This functionality is similar to a class. With a class, it would look like this:

```js
class User {

  // the constructor is ran when you initialize the class.
  constructor(username){
    this._username = username;
  }
  
  greet(greeting){
    if(greeting) return greeting + this._username;
    return `Hi, ${this._username}`;
  }
  
  setName(name){
    if(name) this._username = name;
    return this;
  }
}

// You have to have new to create a new instance of the class.
const user = new User("John Snow");
console.log(user.greet());
user.setName("John Wick");
console.log(user.greet())
console.log(user.setName("John Smith").greet())
```

You can use which ever version you prefer.

Comment: yes w3school is a great reference that's where I learned html and css, I tried learning javascript via w3schools but found it's a bit hard since I came from a non programing course, and js is my first programing language that is why I am learning from youtube tutorials 1st to get a simple explanation, but once i finish my youtube crash course  on js will definitely learn it also from w3schoos  that's what I did when i learned HTML and CSS, yes i came across global and local  function scope before.

Comment: I been learning since 2016, as I want to be a full stack web developer, This is the 5th time I am starting to study JS, one of the reason why i stop is because I encounter lesson that are unclear to me making it hard for me to move forward and eventually losing interest, that's why I am very grateful to those ho helped me with my inquiry earlier , I know it a very basic question  some may even think it's a dumb question to ask, but i just want to really understand the concept, I think this time I'll be able to finish JS this year,